Dropping an unnamed pivoted /r df column
probably a simple question for you but i cant get my head around on how to drop the unnamed maybe pivoted first column. I dont even know the right name of it. Its definitely not a regular column.
Thanks in advance. Really appreciate your help.


I guess the first column is the row names.

Based on your usage of "pivoted," it sounds like you're using tidyr.
Simply use remove_rownames(), as these are the row names, not a column.
